# Replication set for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure

I am trying to follow the instructions for setting up a replication set for a MongoDB database with Azure. The original instructions are at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+on+Azure+VM+-+Linux+Tutorial. I connect the script interpreter with 'mongo --host bsicentos.cloudapp.net --port 27018' (somehting the instructions didn't tell me). The final step instructions me to enter:

```
  > conf = {
      id = “mongors”,
       members : [
           \{id:0, host:”mongodbrs.cloudapp.net:27018\},
           \{id:0, host:”mongodbrs.cloudapp.net:27019\},
           \{id:0, host:”mongodbrs.cloudapp.net:27020\}]}
  >rs.initiate(conf)
```

If I don't type this exactly as specified and I modify it slightly to fit my host (missing closing quotes, not escapes, and id numbers all zero) I finally get an accepted command:

```
mongors:PRIMARY> conf = {
... _id:"mongors",
... members:[
... {_id:0,host:"bsicentos.cloudapp.net:27018"},
... {_id:1,host:"bsicentos.cloudapp.net:27019"},
... {_id:2,host:"bsicentos.cloudapp.net:27020"}]}
{
        "_id" : "mongors",
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "bsicentos.cloudapp.net:27018"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "bsicentos.cloudapp.net:27019"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "bsicentos.cloudapp.net:27020"
                }
        ]
}
```

But I get and error:

```
mongors:PRIMARY> rs.initiate(conf)
{
        "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
        "errmsg" : "already initialized",
        "ok" : 0
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried rs.conf() to see what the current configuration is (to verify it's correct?) If not, consider trying rs.reconfig({...})

Comment: Could you have already sent the command?  If you connect to the shell of one of your nodes, does it give you a prompt like 'PRIMARY>' or 'SECONDARY>'?  Could you connect to one of them and enter the command 'rs.status()', this might be able to get you some insight on the current status of your nodes.  EDIT: judging by the prompt you are seeing "mongors:PRIMARY>", you have already created a replicaset!  You have connected to the primary node of that replicaset to run this command.

Comment: may be useful https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-replication-sets-in-mongodb-on-an-ubuntu-vps and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/